# Using Non-Null Columns in a Default Constraint

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I've learned the hard way that you cannot use a column's value within a default constraint for another column, and that this must be done with a trigger instead.

Attempting to do so will throw the following error:

> The name [ColumnName] is not permitted in this context.  Valid expressions are constants, constant expressions, and (in some cases) variables.  Column names are not permitted.

My question is **why** can't you do this when the other columns are set as NOT NULL?  Since there will always be a value you should always be able to generate a valid default value.    Additionally, what are these cases where variables are allowed?

*Example:*

Let's say I have a function that returns a `NCHAR(5)` called `GenerateIdentifier(@p1, @p2)`

```
CREATE TABLE Employees(
    Id INT NOT NULL IDENTITY (1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    FirstName NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    LastName NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    EmpIdentifier NCHAR(5) NOT NULL
);

ALTER TABLE Employees ADD CONSTRAINT DF_EmpIdentifier DEFAULT GenerateIdentifier([FirstName], [LastName]) FOR EmpIdentifier
```

The `ALTER TABLE` statement would throw that error message.

Comment: Can you expand on this by included your code?

Comment: @SqlZim Sure give me a second

Comment: Consider how complicated this would be become if you changed your not null constraint on a column. But for me the question is why do you want the default value of a column to be the same as another column? That is a red flag to me that something is a bit left of center from a design standpoint.

Comment: @seanlange I see what you're saying, but if the system threw an error if you made it nullable I'd say that wouldn't be too difficult, no?  You're correct on the code smell, but it's passed to a function to generate a value for backwards compatibility purposes.

Comment: Why not simply use ISNULL(Col1, Col2) when calling the function? Or have the function itself do it? As for the engine it would be kind of crazy to have to check every other column in your table to look at the defaults before allowing you to set the nullable property of a column. Logically it doesn't make a lot of sense to have a default that dependent on another column. That is pretty brittle in concept.

Comment: @SeanLange I'm not sure if you're understanding my question.  To simplify the question as much as possible I simply was just looking for why you cannot use another column's value within a default constraint.  There's no reason to call `ISNULL` or anything like that.  If I inserted `('Sean', 'Lange')` then the default constraint would be `GenerateIdentifier('Sean', 'Lange')` since the two parameters are the values in the specified columns that were inserted.

Comment: I answered your question about why. It is a very brittle concept with a lot of overhead for a feature that would be used very rarely but would have a huge impact on every table. In your simple example it would be sort of ok but it is the beginning of a big bowl of spaghetti. By the same logic why can't you use the value of another column but it's default is yet another column's value....suddenly you have the potential for circular logic for defaults based on a very non-standard implementation. It just doesn't hold up logically under scrutiny.

Comment: @SeanLange Ah I get it, that makes sense.  Thanks dude!